# I can not get mysqli_connect to work using Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to use mysqli_connect and I have tried all kinds of variations and none of them have work. They all throw **"No database selected"**. I am having a configuration problem or a code error? THIS WORKS

```
$host = "localhost";
$uname = "root";
$pwd = "";
$database = "testdb";

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $uname, $pwd);
$database = mysql_select_db($database, $conn)
```

I don't know to make this question any clearer,,,I want to use
THESE DO NOT WORK

```
$host = "localhost";
$uname = "root";
$pwd = "";
$database = "testdb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $pwd);
$database = mysqli_select_db($database, $conn);
```

or

```
$host = "localhost";
$uname = "root";
$pwd = "";
$database = "testdb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $pwd, $database);
```

but it is NOT WORKING, I want to know why it is not working and how to make it work using Xampp. It is most likely a configuration problem but I am lost. I have asked this question before there doesn't seem to be anyone that knows how to fix.

Comment: I agree with fred ii and Matts answer. But if you are switching mysql drivers at this time, do yourself a favour and switch to pdo while you're at it. It is not harder to learn and it's what the php developers are recommending to use for new applications.

Comment: Have you verified that the database "testdb" exists?

Comment: Brian. If you disagree with a duplication closure (as I assume you do, looking at your question being a copy paste of your closed one), you need to edit your closed question to highlight why the answers on the dupe don't help you out (and more than "it doesn't help", actual error you got trying them out). This way, your question will go in a review queue and could likely be reopened. Reposting will just lead to similar reaction, and eventually a possible post ban :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this on my live server

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $pwd, $database);
```

There is definitely a configuration problem and I will check further.

Answer (score 1):

`$database = mysqli_select_db($database, $conn);`

Is the incorrect syntax, it's

`mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);`

Additionally, you could delete that line and do the following:

`$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $pwd, $database);`

Comment: This is the exact code I just said didn't work       $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $uname, $pwd, $database);